# Why do I get 'unknown delivery tag' error when I requeue a message in rabbitmq the second time?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

In my application, after I get a message from rabbitmq, I push the message to a client, and wait for its ACK message, if the client doesn't reply with a ACK after some time, I requeue the message in rabbitmq with `basic.reject` with `requeue` being true.

This works fine for the first requeue operation, but after I requeue the same message for the second time, the channel is closed abruptly. From the server log, I get this error:

```
{amqp_error,precondition_failed,"unknown delivery tag 2",'basic.reject'}
```

I gather this is because the message has been removed from the queue. Why is this happening?

Comment: the problem is "unknown delivery tag 2", read here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.delivery-tag   The delivery tag is valid only within the channel from which the message was received. I.e. a client MUST NOT receive a message on one channel and then acknowledge it on another

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the cause, I am using the same channel on the same connection.

Comment: @NeoWang, can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Delivery Tags are unique per delivery. When you rejected the message once, then that particular delivery tag cannot be used again. So I don't understand why you want to reject the same delivery tag twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error

```js
Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1"
    at Channel.C.accept (C:\Owlet\shopify_email_server\node_modules\amqplib\lib\channel.js:422:17)
    at Connection.mainAccept [as accept] (C:\Owlet\shopify_email_server\node_modules\amqplib\lib\connection.js:64:33)
    at Socket.go (C:\Owlet\shopify_email_server\node_modules\amqplib\lib\connection.js:478:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:578:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 406,
  classId: 60,
  methodId: 80
```

My solution was to assert channel with enabled option durable
`channel.assertQueue(queueName, { durable: true });`